# Stop Oracle from generating sqlnet.log file

Tags: perl, oracle

I'm using DBD::Oracle in perl, and whenever a connection fails, the client generates a sqlnet.log file with error details.

The thing is, I already have the error trapped by perl, and in my own log file. I really don't need this extra information.

So, is there a flag or environment for stopping the creation of sqlnet.log?

Comment: +1 - who hasn't found a hundred megabyte sqlnet.log file floating around on their system from time to time :-|

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the metalink

> The logging is automatic, there is no way to turn logging off, but since you are on Unix server, you can redirect the log file to a null device, thus eliminating the problem of disk space consumption.
>
> In the SQLNET.ORA file, set LOG_DIRECTORY_CLIENT and LOG_DIRECTORY_SERVER equal to a null device.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> LOG_DIRECTORY_CLIENT = /dev/null
> LOG_FILE_CLIENT = /dev/null
> ```
>
> in SQLNET.ORA suppresses client logging completely.
>
> To disable the listener from logging, set this parameter in the LISTENER.ORA file:
>
> ```
> logging_listener = off
> ```

Answer (score 6):

As the [Oracle Documentation](http://download-uk.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14212/troublestng.htm#sthref1553) states: To ensure that all errors are recorded, logging cannot be disabled on clients or Names Servers.

You can follow the suggestion of DCookie and use the /dev/null as the log directory. You can use NUL: on windows machines.

Answer (score 4):

Are your clients on Windows, or *nix? If in *nix, you can set LOG_DIRECTORY_CLIENT=/dev/null in your sqlnet.ora file. Not sure if you can do much for a windows client.

EDIT: Doesn't look like it's possible in Windows. The best you could do would be to set the sqlnet.ora parameter above to a fixed location and create a scheduled task to delete the file as desired.

Okay, as Thomas points out there is a null device on windows, use the same paradigm.

Answer (score 3):

IMPORTANT: DO NOT SET "LOG_FILE_CLIENT=/dev/null", this will cause permissions of /dev/null be reset each time your initialize oracle library, and when your umask is something that does not permit world readable-writable bits, those get removed from /dev/null and if you have permission to chmod that file: i.e running as root.

and running as root maybe something trivial, like php --version having oci php-extension present!

full details here:
http://lists.pld-linux.org/mailman/pipermail/pld-devel-en/2014-May/023931.html

you should use path inside directory that doesn't exist:

```
LOG_FILE_CLIENT = /dev/impossible/path
```

and hope nobody creates dir `/dev/impossible` :)

for Windows `NUL` probably is fine as it's not actual file there...

Comment: UPDATE: seems the original fix that appeared to work back then

   LOG_FILE_CLIENT=/dev/impossible/path

is not a good fix, it makes library log again if log path specified is invalid, so i'm in the middle of fork what to do, i don't want the logs nor i don't want /dev/null permissions to be altered.

Comment: you only need to worry about the permissions of `/dev/null` changing, _if_ you run your Oracle-client programs as `root`. Which is usually a bad idea for plenty of other reasons. But if you do have root-powers, you should have no problems creating another null-device (`/dev/ora-null`?) and telling OCI to use that.